# Detecting custom url protocol handler using javascript in windows 10 Edge Browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, microsoft-edge, url-protocol

In our web application we need to find out if a **Custom URL Protocol Handler** is registered or not in windows 10 machine using javascript with **Windows 10 EDGE Browser**.

If the **Custom URL Protocol Handler** is not registered in the windows 10 machine we will ask the user to download our desktop standalone app.
If registered we will start our desktop standalone app using the registered **Custom URL Protocol Handler**.

Since EDGE is a new browser the solutions provided by other users in the internet are not working.

Links I referred that are not working for me in EDGE browser:

https://gist.github.com/keyvanfatehi/f2f521c654bab106fdf9

Please help me out,
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this workaround helps:

Whenever you navigate to an unkown protocol with MS Edge, Windows asks the user about the app to handle this protocol. You could just navigate to your protocol and display a message with some information about what to do if the tool does not open. Something like this (sorry for the German screenshot):

```html
<div id="toolBox">
    <p id="toolBoxText"></p>
 <input type="button" id="toolButton" onclick="openTool()" value="Start tool" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function openTool(){
         window.location = 'myprotocol://command/';
         document.getElementById("toolButton").value = "Try again";
         document.getElementById("toolBoxText").innerHTML = "Thank you for using our tool. If the tool did not open successfully, please first download and install the tool <a href='download/'>here</a> and then try again."
        }
</script>
```

[image]